# Linked List push()

Tags: c++, linked-list, add-in

The stack is initialized with a int MaxSize =3.  Then I push one int onto the list. " Pushed:" is returned to the console.  Program crashes here.  I think my logic is flawed but unsure.  Maybe an infinite loop or unmet condition?  Thanks for your help.

I'm trying to traverse the list to the last node in the second part of the full() method.  I implemented this stack as array based so must implement this method full() as this method is inside of main class.

```
while(!stacker.full()) {
    cout << "Enter number = ";
    cin >> intIn;
    stacker.push(intIn);
    cout << "Pushed: " << intIn <<  endl;
}//while
```

Call to LinkListStack.cpp to class LinkList full().

```
int LinkList::full() {
    if(head == NULL) {
        top = 0;
    } else {
        LinkNode * tmp1;
        LinkNode * tmp2;
        tmp1 = head;
        while(top != MaxSize) {
            if(tmp1->next != NULL){
                tmp2 = tmp1->next;
                tmp1 = tmp2;
                ++top;
            }//if
        }//while
    }//else
return (top + 1 == MaxSize);
}
```

The push method here:

```
void LinkList::push(int numIn) {
    LinkNode * nodeIn = new LinkNode(numIn);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = nodeIn;
    }else {
        nodeIn = head;
        head = nodeIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Stack class in C++?

Comment: `top` seems to be a data member of LinkList. But what is its purpose? You just increase it in your else branch without setting it to 0. Why don't you just remember the actual size and avoid traversing the list? You should probably make `full` a `const` member function. I don't think `full` is really supposed to mutate your list. Also, `tmp2` is useless. You could have just written `tmp1 = tmp1->next`.

Comment: How does your 'push' method look like? Its obviously one of the problems with your code.

Comment: When you push a new node on top of the stack you need to make sure the link to the previous top is not lost i.e. nodeIn->next=head; head=nodeIn;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your  while loop in full():

```
while(top != MaxSize) {
        if(tmp1->next != NULL){
            tmp2 = tmp1->next;
            tmp1 = tmp2;
            ++top;
        }//if
    }//while
```

So if you have one element in the list you enter the while loop(assuming `top == 0` ?), and since it's the first node in the list `tmp1->next` is `NULL`, which keeps top from being incremented, so you're stuck in the loop.

You also shouldn't need `tmp2`, you can just use `tmp1 = tmp1 -> next;`.

And to correct the problem look at the if statment, Why are you checking to make sure the next node is not null?

Also, look in push():

```
void LinkList::push(int numIn) {
    LinkNode * nodeIn = new LinkNode(numIn);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = nodeIn;
    }else {
        nodeIn = head;
        head = nodeIn;
    }
}
```

You should be setting `nodeIn->next` to `head`, before pointing `head` at `nodeIn`.  The way it is written the new node is never added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
int LinkList::full() {
        int top = 0;
        LinkNode * tmp1;
        tmp1 = head;
        while(top <= MaxSize && tmp1 != NULL) {
                tmp1 = tmp1->next;
                ++top;
        }//while
    return (top <= MaxSize);
}
```

Comment: The stack will not terminate at MaxSize.  I can continue to add inputs past the Maxsize parameter??